# How to enable partial loading in Service Trace Viewer for files < 40 mb

Tags: wcf, trace

I'm currently trying to load a 32MB trace file in the Service Trace Viewer tool, but performance is dreadful. At this pace it will take about half an hour to process. Something that I think should be prevented by partial loading. Microsoft says the following on the matter:

> You do not need to manually enable
>   partial loading. If the total size of
>   the trace file(s) you attempt to load
>   exceeds 40MB, Service Trace Viewer
>   automatically displays a Partial
>   Loading dialog for you to select the
>   part that you want to load.

Is there really not a way to enable this for files smaller than 40MB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) keep some of your older logs that is only very little bit bigger than 40MB

2) drop together your old and new xml-log to SvcTraceViewer window

3) partial loading window appears

4) select time range you need

5) unless you select too broad timerange the old xml-log is not loaded